# avoiding a page reloading and scrolling for a page with many submit buttons

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

I am displaying a status of a device on a webpage. I want to make sure that the operator of the device sees the status. Device sends status every minute. So my page updates the data every minute. there is a form button corresponding to  each status so that the operator can click (ACCEPT STATUS) it and update a table in my database (SEENORNOT). The problem is, if there is no operator for a while, the page will be filled up with data. In that case, the operator has to scroll back each time after clicking a button. I mean, for example, there is 100 status to accept at the moment.  if I can see a maximum of 20 numbers on the screen without scrolling if I scroll to any value more than 20 and accept it, the screen will go back to the initial stage. I am trying to avoid this scrolling and Update the page without a refresh. Any suggestions. At the moment I am refreshing the entire page to update data every minute. I hope i can avoid it using ajax.

```
#db connection and getting data here- not shown here
<div class ="deviceStatus">
<table class="myTable">
<tr>
     <th >Status</th>
     <th >Seen or Not</th>
     <th >Button to accept</th>
</tr>
<form class="" action="status.php" method="get">
<tr>
<?php
    echo "<td>" . $row["STATUS"]. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["SEENORNOT"]. "</td>";
    echo "<td>"." <input type=hidden  name=hidden value =" . $row["ID"]."  </td>";
    echo "<td>"." <input type=submit name=accept value=Accept id=button1 class = MyButton"."  </td>";
?>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
</div>

# on button press I am updating the DB table (SEENORNOT) value using the ID.
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please use alternate syntax when using PHP and HTML.

```
#db connection and getting data here- not shown here
<div class ="deviceStatus">
    <table class="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                 <th>Status</th>
                 <th>Seen or Not</th>
                 <th>Button to accept</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach($query as $row): ?> <!--Please update $query with your resultset-->
                <tr>
                    <td><?=$row["STATUS"]?></td>
                    <td><?=$row["SEENORNOT"]?></td>
                    <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="button1" class="accept_btn" tag="<?=$row['id']?>">Accept</a></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

# on button press I am updating the DB table (SEENORNOT) value using the ID.
```

Second, please don't be scared to use Ajax, because it is what you will need in this case.
I gave you a headstart here, please use it.

```
<script>
$('.accept_btn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let button = $(this).attr('tag');

    alert('Clicked button with row #' + button);
});
</script>
```

Comment: what do you mean by alternative syntax

Comment: @dayDreamer `<?php if ($test == true):?> rather than `<?php if($test == true) { ?>` And `<?='Hello'?>` rather than `<?php echo 'Hello'; ?>`